# Sums of binomial expressions returns different and sometimes indeterminate expressions

Tags: summation, assumptions, combinatorics

A problem that I encountered multiple times when taking sums over expressions involving binomials, factorials, etc. is that Mathematica (version 11.2) returns indeterminate expressions when it should not.

An example:

> If an urn contains `n` balls out of which `q` balls are red and `n-q`
>   balls are blue. There are `Binomial[q, z]*Binomial[n - q, k - z]`
>   possibilities for drawing `k` balls out of the urn so that `z` drawn balls
>   are red and `k-z` drawn balls are blue. Summing over all possible values of
>   `z`, one should obtain the total number of possibilities to draw `k` balls
>   from the urn (regardless their colour). This number is
>   `Binomial[n,k]`.

Let's get Mathematica to compute this.

```
Sum[Binomial[q, z]*Binomial[n - q, k - z], {z, 0, k}]
```

This returns

```
((-1)^(2 + k) (-1 + k - n)!)/(k! (-1 - n)!)
```

This expression is indeterminate because `(-1 + k - n)!` and `(-1 - n)!` evaluate to `ComplexInfinity`.

I can get Mathematica to produce the correct result by substituting `n->k0+k`:

```
Sum[Binomial[q, z]*Binomial[k0 + k - q, k - z], {z, 0, k}]
```

This returns

```
(k + k0)!/(k! k0!)
```

which simplifies to `Binomial[n,k]` if I reverse the substitution.

It seems unsatisfying to me that Mathematica's result depend so sensitively on the way I define my variables. Why is that so and what can I do to ensure that I always define my variables in a way that Mathematica produces the correct results?

I have tried using assumptions but with no success. The lines

```
Assuming[n > k, Sum[Binomial[q, z]*Binomial[n - q, k - z], {z, 0, k}]]
Assuming[k0 > 0, Sum[Binomial[q, z]*Binomial[k0 + k - q, k - z], {z, 0, k}]]
```

produce the same results as if I wouldn't use `Assuming`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s2 = Sum[Binomial[q, z]*Binomial[n - q, k - z], {z, 0, k}, 
  Assumptions -> {q, z, n, k} \[Element] Integers && k <= q && k - z <= n - q]
```

> ((-1)^(1 + k) n Pochhammer[1 - n, -1 + k])/k!

```
FullSimplify[s2 == Binomial[n, k], Assumptions -> {n, k} \[Element] Integers && k <= n]
```

> True